# What is the term that describes the opposite in a pair?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Say you have a database record, with a field `operation`, which can have the values `checkIn` or `checkOut`. If you have one of the two records, how do you call the other record?

I thought of `complement` and `counter_record`, but I would appreciate more ideas.